# "Expecting class or interface declaration at or before "void" "

Tags: java

I'm completing this java program and the error message "Expecting class or interface declaration at or before "void" " is very hard to resolve. It's confusing because I have the same "public static void" setup for two calls before. I don't think it's because the call is outside of the main method. What am I missing? My work is provided below.

```
    import java.util.Scanner; //needed for input

    public class Holidaycharitydonations {
    static double[] cashDonations = new double[6];

    static double[] lbsFood = new double[6]; 

    static String[] siteName = new String[6]; 
    static String bestSiteCash = " "; 

    static String bestSiteFood = " "; 

    static double totalCash = 0; 

    static double totalFood = 0; 

    static double maxFood = 0; 
    static double maxCash = 0; 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String runAgain = "yes"; //use runAgain

    do {

     getDonations();
     processDonations();
     displayDonations();


     System.out.print("Enter yes if you want to run again: ");
     runAgain = input.next();
     input.nextLine(); 
     System.out.print("\n\n\n");
      } while (runAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));

      } // end of main

    public static void getDonations() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 

   for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
     System.out.println("Enter site " + (i + 1) + " name: ");
     siteName[i] = input.next();
     input.nextLine();//fixes skipping issue

     System.out.println("Enter cash donation(USD) for" + siteName[i] + ":   ");
     cashDonations[i] = input.nextDouble();
     while (cashDonations[i] < 1 )
     {
        System.out.println("SORRY - must be greater than 1 USD");
        System.out.print("Enter cash donation(USD) for " + siteName[i] + ": ");
        cashDonations[i] = input.nextDouble();
     }
     System.out.println("Enter food donation(lbs.) for " + siteName[i] + ": ");
     lbsFood[i] = input.nextDouble();

     while (lbsFood[i] < 1)
     {
        System.out.println("SORRY - must be greater than 1lb");
        System.out.println("Enter food donation(lbs.) for " + siteName[i] + ": ");
        lbsFood[i] = input.nextDouble();
     }

        }

}

    public static void processDonations() {
    totalCash = 0;
    totalFood = 0;
    maxCash = cashDonations[0];
    maxFood = lbsFood[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
    {
     if (cashDonations[i] > maxCash)
     {
        maxCash = cashDonations[i];
        bestSiteCash = siteName[i];
     } 
     if (lbsFood[i] > maxFood)
     {
        maxFood = lbsFood[i];
        bestSiteFood = siteName[i];
     } 
     }//End of for loop


     for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)

     totalCash = totalCash + cashDonations[i];
     totalFood = totalFood + lbsFood[i];
     }
     }//end of processDonations


     public static void displayDonations() {

     System.out.println("\n\n\n");
     System.out.println("\tHOLIDAY DONATION LOCATIONS REPORT\t");
     System.out.println("\t---------------------------------\t");
     System.out.println("\n\n\n");


    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
   System.out.print("Site:" + siteName[i]); 
   System.out.print("Individual Cash Donations: $" + cashDonations[i]);
   System.out.print("Individual Food Donations:" + lbsFood[i]+ "lbs" );
   System.out.print("\n");

   }//End of for loop

   System.out.print("\tHoliday Donation Totals Report\t");
   System.out.println("\t----------------------------\t");

   System.out.println("Total Cash Donations are $" + totalCash );
   System.out.println("Total Food Donations are " + totalFood + "lbs" );
   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("\tHoliday Donation Best Site Report\t");
   System.out.println("\t---------------------------------\t");  

   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("Best location site for cash donation:" + bestSiteCash );
   System.out.println("Max cash collected was:" + maxCash );

   System.out.println("\n");
   System.out.println("Best location site for food donation:" + bestSiteFood );
   System.out.println("Max food collected was:" + maxFood );
   }// end of displayDonations()


   }// end of class
```

Comment: And where, exactly, does the compiler give you this error message? Which line of your code? Also, your indenting is horrendous. You might have mismatched braces, but it's near impossible to tell.

Comment: Where the hell is your IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,  you missed `{` after for loop declaration

```
    ... 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        totalCash = totalCash + cashDonations[i];
        totalFood = totalFood + lbsFood[i];
    } 
}//end of processDonations
```

It should be

```
    ... 
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        totalCash = totalCash + cashDonations[i];
        totalFood = totalFood + lbsFood[i];
    } 
}//end of processDonations
```